# How to Encrypt a Message With an Encryption Key

Tags: java, encryption

I'm attempting to write a small encryption program. One of the options is "encrypt with key". The thing I can't figure out is how to create a way to encrypt a message based on a String.

```
public static void encodeWithKey(){
    System.out.println("What is the encryption key?");
    String encryptKey = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("What is the message to encrypt?");
    String messageWithKey = scan.nextLine();

    StringBuilder encryptWithKeyBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for (char c : messageWithKey.toCharArray()) {
      // Add 1 to each character and append it
      encryptWithKeyBuilder.append((char) (c - 1));
    }

    // Now the builder contains the String with the shifted values
    System.out.println("Your encoded message is: ");
    System.out.print(encryptWithKeyBuilder);

}
```

I want to find the first two letters of their encrypt key, convert them to integers, and add them together. Then use that to encrypt the message (in the for loop, replacing the '1' with the new number.)

Comment: which difficulties do you have with this?

Comment: @nazar_art I just don't know how to do it. Im relatively new to Java (less than 1 year) and am mostly self taught.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the sum of the first letters of the encryption key as follows:

```
int firstLettersSum = (int)encryptKey.charAt(0) + (int)encryptKey.charAt(1)
```

Comment: This looks promising. Changing classes now, so it'll probably be accepted in 10 mins

Comment: It doesn't work sadly. I used that code, and reversed it for the decode, but the text doesn;t match